# Why application crashes after signing?

Tags: macos, code-signing

The problem is that my app bundle works before signing and crashes if I use `codesign` and I am absolutely clueless as to how find out the reasons. Can someone push me in the right direction?

I am getting this report. I assume the software starts correctly (yes?), loads libraries without problems (yes?), but then does some check and fails. What could I check to find the reason of the crash?

```
-------------------------------------
Translated Report (Full Report Below)
-------------------------------------

Process:               bla [1386]
Path:                  /Users/USER/Desktop/*/bla.app/Contents/MacOS/bla
Identifier:            firma.bla
Version:               1.2.572 (1.2.572)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        launchd [1]
User ID:               504

Date/Time:             2023-11-13 14:51:17.7531 +0100
OS Version:            macOS 12.5 (21G72)
Report Version:        12
Anonymous UUID:        1B6A...

Sleep/Wake UUID:       1588...

Time Awake Since Boot: 4500 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000001, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Reason:    Namespace CODESIGNING, Code 2 

Thread 0 Crashed::  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
...
```

I've read about signing process and tried few things, namely I can re-sign previous version of the same bundle, exactly like I am doing with the newer and there are no problems. I've compared entitlements, they are identical. The new app bundle uses new framework and has lots of changes in source code, but they both works unsigned and then newer one stops working after signing. Why?

---

I copy app bundle and run it - works.

Then I sign the file and the app like this:

```
% codesign --no-strict --force --timestamp --options=runtime --entitlements "bla.entitlements" --sign "Developer ID Application: ..." "bla.app/Contents/MacOS/bla"
% codesign ... "bla.app"
```

Then I verify signing

```
% codesign --verify --verbose bla.app
bla.app: valid on disk
bla.app: satisfies its Designated Requirement
```

And then I start it directly by double clicking or from terminal and it crashes

```
% ./bla.app/Contents/MacOS/bla
zsh: killed     ./bla.app/Contents/MacOS/bla
```

What should I do?

Comment: It might need to be [notorized by Apple](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/security/notarizing_macos_software_before_distribution?language=objc).  Create an [app password](https://support.apple.com/en-gb/102654), zip-up the app using `ditto -ck --rsrc --sequesterRsrc --keepParent /path/to/YourApp.app YourApp.zip` and then try `xcrun notarytool submit --apple-id "your-apple-id@whatever.com" --password <app-password> --team-id <dev-team-id> --wait YourApp.zip` (where `<app-password>` is your app password, and `<dev-team-id>` is your 10-digit team ID).

Comment: @trojanfoe, not in my case. I wonder how crash for notarization error would looks like. If it also says "EXC_CRASH (SIGKILL (Code Signature Invalid))", then I am sorry for apple-developers ;)

Answer (score 1):

This cryptic error doesn't tell about **specific reason** of the crash, which in my case was missing entitlement. Sure, it's code-signing related, but... /sigh

If someone could post an answer, how to find out specific reason of the code-signing crash, that would be very helpful. I am posting my answer to tell few things and solutin to my specific problem.

What I figured out:

1. This error means you have code-signing issue.
2. Your software is fine, check **only** code-signing, don't waste your time elsewhere.
3. Unless signed software is downloaded (which then envolves gatekeeper, can't tell much about it), this error has nothing to do with notarization, don't pursue further until signed software works similarly to the unsigned one.

I wish the report would contain a hint what it is the missing entitlement. My previous app-bundle uses .Net 5 and the new one uses .Net 7. I had to edit entitlement file to change below key to a `true`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    ...
    <key>com.apple.security.cs.allow-unsigned-executable-memory</key>
    <true/>
    ...
</dict>
</plist>
```

After that my app-bundle continue working after signing.